What is the meaning of the phrasal verb "put out" in this sentence?

He put out food for the birds.

For me it means that you just give food to the birds in your garden say, but I am not sure. In Cambridge Dictionary there is a meaning of "producing something in large quantities" so could it also mean this?

He produced large quantities of food for some birds.


Your first meaning is correct. He placed some food outside for birds to eat.

It's the following definition from NOAD (Cambridge doesn't seem to have any corresponding entry):

(put something out, put out something) lay something out ready for use: she put out glasses and paper napkins.

It doesn't say anything about the quantity of food.
